# Sending and Receiving Push notifications on a Progressive Webapp using Pubnub

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, pubnub, web-push, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive WebApp Chat application and I want to be able to be able to send or receive Push Notifications (on Mobile) and Web (Chrome) Notifications while on Desktop. Right now, I have a web client that is able to receive ***tickles*** i.e. data without payloads (payloads will then be fetched through an API call from my server)

I am using **Pubnub** to talk to **GCM** and **APNS**. I have working apps on *Web, iOS(native) and Android(native)* clients of my project. Right now, I am able to receive Push Notifications on my web app but without the payload.

No where is the server *publishing* anything. All publishes are done by the clients since its mainly a chat app.

From my Web/Android client, my **pubnubPayload** is:

```
var pubnubPayload = {
    "text": "no payload!",
    "pn_gcm": {
        "data": {
            "title": "shash",
            "babe": "ya"
        }
    }
}
```

And then do a normal publish like this:

```
Pubnub.publish({
    channel: myChannel,
    message: pubnubPayload,
    callback: someFunc
});
```

So, when I subscribe to a pubnub channel like this:

```
    Pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: selectedChannel,
        message: function(m){
            console.log(m)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Handle error here
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

I receive the message through Pubnub AND a push notification (but *without* the payload) on my webapp.

**My question is:**

How do I receive push notifications on web that have a payload? Is there someway pubnub lets you publish encrypted messages for webs client to be able to read the payload of the GCM push notification **without** using [**Pubnub's Access Manager**](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security)?

Or is using PAM my only option and should fix the no payload issue?

Comment: @PubNub, I hope you guys have an answer to this as I couldn't find anything on the web to do this.

Comment: Not sure what you are using for *web push notifications*. Is this browser notifications? If so, didn't think this was cross-browser and only worked with Chrome. Perhaps seeing more of your code would be helpful. About Access Manager, it does not encrypt your data. Enable `ssl` param and provide `cipher_key` in `PUBNUB.int` to do that. Let me know if we can see more of your code to get more context on the web push side of things. Looks like you are using PubNub JavaScript SDK v3. We recommend [PubNub JS SDK v4](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk)

Comment: @CraigConover I want to receive push notifications(on the browser in Android, iOS and Web) on our Progressive Webapp built with AngularJS running your v3 JS SDK. Following this : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en .
Check this out https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/. The issue is I want to receive the payload contained in the push (that was sent from one of our clients ie Android, Web or iOS), as web app requires encryption on the payload in order to read it.

Comment: Ok, I just saw that PAM is free across all usage tiers. So I could go ahead and implement it anyways, but will PAM solve this issue? Also can we apply cipher_key without PAM being enabled?

Comment: Not sure I following you on this one: "web app requires encryption on the payload in order to read it". Why does it have to be encrypted? Either way, PubNub will encrypt the whole payload and decrypt the whole payload automatically but the push payload is not something that PubNub will process on the receiving end because it is not the receiving agent of the push payload (your device is: browser, phone, etc).

Comment: Access Manager does not enable encryption nor does it facilitate it. It only provides a means for verifying access to channels using auth-keys that you grant permissions to (read and write).

Comment: @CraigConover check this out. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption?hl=en

Comment: So do you encrypt publish payload when dispatching to push services like gcm or apns?

Comment: If you use a cipher key when you init PubNub, then the entire PubNub published payload is encrypted. This means PubNub won't know there is a push payload to send to APNS/GCM so you would need to use encrypt/decrypt methods in our SDK to encrypt only the data that needs encrypting.

Comment: @CraigConover Do you have an example of a progressive web app implementing sending/receiving push notifications with payload sent using pubnub.publish() method and mobile gateway enabled?

Comment: No, we do not. Just now heard of Progressive from this thread.

Comment: Ok, so if you don't encrypt it, how to I send it in pubnub.publish() such that my Progressive web app can receive this payload on mobile web? What do I need to do this?

Comment: Encryption is not required to publish. You can just enable TLS and it will only be encrypted from client to PubNub and PubNub will be able to send the push notification. The actual push notification will not be encrypted when it is sent from PubNub to APNS/GCM and from APNS/GCM to the client device(s).

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Access Manager not required for Message Encryption

[PubNub Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security) and message encryption are not directly related and is not required to encrypt your messages, but all applications using PubNub [should implement Access Manager to control who can do what on channels](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/tutorials/pubnub-access-manager) by [granting permissions (read/write/delete) to auth-keys](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-access-manager) that your client apps will init PubNub with to use those channels as you intended.

### Encrypt using Standard TLS (formerly known as SSL)

To encrypt messages, simply initialize PubNub with TLS enabled (`ssl` might be the name of the parameter but it is the latest TLS, not the old SSL that was deprecated). This will use standard TLS encryption from your server or client apps to the PubNub network.

### Encrypt messages using Cipher Key for AES 256 Encryption

If you wish to have your messages encrypted from your server/client apps to PubNub and all throughout PubNub, just [provide a cipher key when you initialize PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security#message_layer_encryption_with_aes256_2). The best part about this is that you hold the keys, not PubNub, so no one can read your messages except the holders of those cipher keys.

#### Custom Encryption using the encrypt/decrypt API

The question asked here includes mobile push notifications which means you can't encrypt the full message if you want the mobile push message to be sent by PubNub to the push services (APNS/FCM) and handled by those services properly. The realtime message will be sent as is - encrypted - to the client subscribers. But you can encrypt the important/confidential parts of the message and leave the parts that need to be ready by PubNub and the push services unencrypted [using the `encrypt` and `decrypt` APIs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-misc#encrypt). The article, [Encryption for APNS, GCM, WMS with PubNub](https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006328), is a bit old but should provide the required insights.